# 3d - TiKZ: How to join the 2 faces of a cylinder?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I have the code below to draw the terminal faces of a cylinder shown in horizontal direction.
I would like to complete the figure with the 2 lines that show the wall tube.

[image]

I guess there is something to do with:

```
\tdplottransformmainscreen{?}{?}{?}
\draw[tdplot_screen_coords] (??,??) -- (??,??);
```

Here is my code:

```
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, tdplot_main_coords]
%
% set some parameterts 
\def \ra{3.5};
\def \dfi{-25};
\def \dr{0.5};
\def \tetM{150};
\def \rM{2.5};
%
% draw axis
\draw[line width=0.3mm,->,>={Latex[length=6]}](0,0,0)--(3,0,0)node[below]{\emph{x}};
\draw[line width=0.3mm,->,>={Latex[length=6]}](0,0,0)--(0,7,0)node[above]{\emph{y}};
\draw[line width=0.3mm,->,>={Latex[length=6]}](0,0,0)--(0,0,7)node[left=-3pt]{\emph{z}};
\draw[line width=0.7mm,-stealth](0,0)--(1,0)node[pos=0.9, above]{$\vec{u}_x$};
\draw[line width=0.7mm,-stealth](0,0)--(0,1)node[pos=0.8, below]{$\vec{u}_y$};
\draw[line width=0.7mm,-stealth](0,0,0)--(0,0,1)node[pos=0.7, left]{$\vec{u}_z$};
%
% draw the back disk face
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{90}{0}
\coordinate (Shift) at (-9,0,0);
\tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(Shift)}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw []({\ra},0) arc[start angle=0, delta angle=360, radius={\ra}];
\end{scope}
%
% draw the front disk face
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{90}{0}
\coordinate (Shift) at (0,0,0);
\tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(Shift)}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw [thick]({\ra},0) arc[start angle=0, delta angle=360, radius={\ra}];
\coordinate (M) at (\tetM:\rM);
\coordinate (Mp) at (\tetM+\dfi:\rM);
\coordinate (Mr) at (\tetM:\rM+\dr);
\coordinate (Mpr) at (\tetM+\dfi:\rM+\dr);
\fill[gray!50,opacity=0.5](\tetM:{\rM}) arc[start angle=\tetM, delta angle=\dfi, radius={\rM}] -- (Mpr) arc[start angle=\tetM+\dfi, delta angle=-\dfi, radius={\rM+\dr}]--(M);
\draw [line width=0.7mm](\tetM:{\rM}) arc[start angle=\tetM, delta angle=\dfi, radius={\rM}] -- (Mpr)node[pos=0.5,below,sloped]{$dr$} arc[start angle=\tetM+\dfi, delta angle=-\dfi, radius={\rM+\dr}]--(M);
\draw[fill,red](\tetM+\dfi/2:\rM+\dr/2)circle(1.5pt);
\draw[line width=0.7mm,->,>=Stealth,red]({\tetM+\dfi/2}:\rM+\dr/2)--++(0,0,1.5)node[below right=-3pt]{$d\vec{S}$};
\draw[line width=0.7mm](M)--(\tetM:0)node[pos=0.3,above,sloped]{$r$};
\draw[dashed](\tetM:0)--(\tetM:5);
\draw[dashed](\tetM+\dfi:0)--(\tetM+\dfi:5);
\draw [-{>[length=6]},thick](180:{4}) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-180+\tetM, radius={4}]node[pos=0.5,above]{$\theta$};
\draw [-{>[length=6]},line width=0.7mm](\tetM:{4}) arc[start angle=\tetM, delta angle=\dfi, radius={4}]node[pos=0.5,above right=3pt]{$d\theta$};
\end{scope}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, tdplot_main_coords]
  %
  % set some parameters 
  \def\ra{3.5};
  \def\dfi{-25};
  \def\dr{0.5};
  \def\tetM{150};
  \def\rM{2.5};
  %
  % draw axis
  \draw[line width=0.3mm,->,>={Latex[length=6]}](0,0,0)--(3,0,0)node[below]{\emph{x}};
  \draw[line width=0.3mm,->,>={Latex[length=6]}](0,0,0)--(0,7,0)node[above]{\emph{y}};
  \draw[line width=0.3mm,->,>={Latex[length=6]}](0,0,0)--(0,0,7)node[left=-3pt]{\emph{z}};
  \draw[line width=0.7mm,-stealth](0,0)--(1,0)node[pos=0.9, above]{$\vec{u}_x$};
  \draw[line width=0.7mm,-stealth](0,0)--(0,1)node[pos=0.8, below]{$\vec{u}_y$};
  \draw[line width=0.7mm,-stealth](0,0,0)--(0,0,1)node[pos=0.7, left]{$\vec{u}_z$};
  %
  % draw the back disk face
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{90}{0}
  \coordinate (Shift) at (-9,0,0);
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(Shift)}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
  \draw []({\ra},0)  arc[start angle=0, delta angle=360, radius={\ra}];
  \end{scope}
  %
  % draw the front disk face
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{90}{0}
  \coordinate (Shift) at (0,0,0);
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(Shift)}
  \path (-9,0,0) coordinate (M2);
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
    \path (0,0) coordinate (M1);
    \shade let \p1=($(M1)-(M2)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
     [top color=black,bottom color=black!80,middle color=gray!20,shading angle=\n1,
      opacity=0.8]
     ($(M1)+(\n1+90:\ra)$) -- ($(M2)+(\n1+90:\ra)$)
     arc(\n1+90:\n1+270:\ra) -- ($(M1)+(\n1+270:\ra)$)
     arc(\n1+270:\n1+90:\ra);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
    \draw [thick]({\ra},0) arc[start angle=0, delta angle=360, radius={\ra}];
    \coordinate (M) at (\tetM:\rM);
    \coordinate (Mp) at (\tetM+\dfi:\rM);
    \coordinate (Mr) at (\tetM:\rM+\dr);
    \coordinate (Mpr) at (\tetM+\dfi:\rM+\dr);
    \fill[gray!50,opacity=0.5](\tetM:{\rM}) arc[start angle=\tetM, delta angle=\dfi, radius={\rM}] -- (Mpr) arc[start angle=\tetM+\dfi, delta angle=-\dfi, radius={\rM+\dr}]--(M);
    \draw [line width=0.7mm](\tetM:{\rM}) arc[start angle=\tetM, delta angle=\dfi, radius={\rM}] -- (Mpr)node[pos=0.5,below,sloped]{$dr$} arc[start angle=\tetM+\dfi, delta angle=-\dfi, radius={\rM+\dr}]--(M);
    \draw[fill,red](\tetM+\dfi/2:\rM+\dr/2)circle(1.5pt);
    \draw[line width=0.7mm,->,>=Stealth,red]({\tetM+\dfi/2}:\rM+\dr/2)--++(0,0,1.5)node[below right=-3pt]{$d\vec{S}$};
    \draw[line width=0.7mm](M)--(\tetM:0)node[pos=0.3,above,sloped]{$r$};
    \draw[dashed](\tetM:0)--(\tetM:5);
    \draw[dashed](\tetM+\dfi:0)--(\tetM+\dfi:5);
    \draw [-{>[length=6]},thick](180:{4}) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-180+\tetM, radius={4}]node[pos=0.5,above]{$\theta$};
    \draw [-{>[length=6]},line width=0.7mm](\tetM:{4}) arc[start angle=\tetM, delta angle=\dfi, radius={4}]node[pos=0.5,above right=3pt]{$d\theta$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that I used the `3d` library for that because I find it more intuitive. And I think you could use it all over instead of switching to all these rotated coordinate systems. Here is what I got.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, tdplot_main_coords]
  %
  % set some parameters 
  \def\ra{3.5};
  \def\dfi{-25};
  \def\dr{0.5};
  \def\tetM{150};
  \def\rM{2.5};
  %
  % draw the back disk face
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=-9]
   \draw (0,0) coordinate (M2) circle[radius=\ra];
  \end{scope}
  %
  % draw the front disk face
  %\path (-9,0,0) coordinate (M2);
  \begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0,xscale=-1]
    \path (0,0) coordinate (M1);
    \shade let \p1=($(M1)-(M2)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
     [top color=black,bottom color=black!80,middle color=gray!20,
     shading angle=\n1+90,opacity=1]
     ($(M1)+(\n1-90:\ra)$) -- ($(M2)+(\n1-90:\ra)$)
     arc(\n1-90:\n1+90:\ra) -- ($(M1)+(\n1+90:\ra)$)
     arc(\n1+90:\n1-90:\ra);
    \shade let \p1=($(M1)-(M2)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
     [top color=black,bottom color=black!80,middle color=gray!20,
     shading angle=\n1+90,opacity=0.6]
     ($(M1)+(\n1+90:\ra)$) -- ($(M2)+(\n1+90:\ra)$)
     arc(\n1+90:\n1+270:\ra) -- ($(M1)+(\n1+270:\ra)$)
     arc(\n1+270:\n1+90:\ra);
    \draw[thick] (M1) circle [radius=\ra];
    \coordinate (M) at (\tetM:\rM);
    \coordinate (Mp) at (\tetM+\dfi:\rM);
    \coordinate (Mr) at (\tetM:\rM+\dr);
    \coordinate (Mpr) at (\tetM+\dfi:\rM+\dr);
    \fill[gray!50,opacity=0.5](\tetM:{\rM}) arc[start angle=\tetM, delta angle=\dfi, radius={\rM}] -- (Mpr) arc[start angle=\tetM+\dfi, delta angle=-\dfi, radius={\rM+\dr}]--(M);
    \draw [line width=0.7mm](\tetM:{\rM}) arc[start angle=\tetM, delta angle=\dfi, radius={\rM}] -- 
    (Mpr)node[pos=0.5,below,sloped,rotate=90]{$\mathrm{d}r$} arc[start angle=\tetM+\dfi, delta angle=-\dfi, radius={\rM+\dr}]--(M);
    \draw[fill,red](\tetM+\dfi/2:\rM+\dr/2) coordinate (P) circle(1.5pt);
    \draw[line width=0.7mm](M1)--(M)node[pos=0.7,above,sloped,rotate=90]{$r$};
    \draw[dashed](\tetM:0)--(\tetM:5);
    \draw[dashed](\tetM+\dfi:0)--(\tetM+\dfi:5);
    \draw [-{>[length=6]},thick](180:{4}) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-180+\tetM, radius={4}]node[pos=0.5,above]{$\theta$};
    \draw [-{>[length=6]},line width=0.7mm](\tetM:{4}) arc[start angle=\tetM, delta angle=\dfi, radius={4}]node[pos=0.5,above right=3pt]{$d\theta$};
  \end{scope}
  \draw[line width=0.7mm,->,>=Stealth,red](P)--++(1.5,0,0)node[below right=-3pt]
  {$\mathrm{d}\vec{S}$};
  % draw axes
  \draw[line width=0.3mm,->,>={Latex[length=6]}](0,0,0)--(3,0,0)node[below]{\emph{x}};
  \draw[line width=0.3mm,->,>={Latex[length=6]}](0,0,0)--(0,7,0)node[above]{\emph{y}};
  \draw[line width=0.3mm,->,>={Latex[length=6]}](0,0,0)--(0,0,7)node[left=-3pt]{\emph{z}};
  \draw[line width=0.7mm,-stealth](0,0)--(1,0)node[pos=0.9, above]{$\vec{u}_x$};
  \draw[line width=0.7mm,-stealth](0,0)--(0,1)node[pos=0.8, below]{$\vec{u}_y$};
  \draw[line width=0.7mm,-stealth](0,0,0)--(0,0,1)node[pos=0.7, left]{$\vec{u}_z$};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, that's exactly what I need.
You're right, your second proposition better fits.

Comment: What do you mean by accepting it? I guess I had to clic on the "green check" right?
I have copy-past your solution and as I said, it works fine. But it remains quite obscure for me. I can't figure out what 'let', '\p1', '\n1'... do.
If you know any ressource I could read to learn more about that, it will be very helpfull.

Comment: @JulienFaure Thanks! The syntax `let \p1=($(M1)-(M2)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in ` measures the 2d (!) slope of a line that connects the centers of the circles. Given the slope, it is then clear where the tangents which we are looking for attach to the circles. These tangents define the boundaries of the cylinder. The slope angle, `\n1`, is also used to rotate the shading, which should be along the direction of the tangents.